# filter minimum value from custom java array list

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Am having a custom array list `UserDeactivationThreshold` from that i want to get the minimum `thresholdvalue`

for example. Please find the output from `toString()` method.

```
UserDeactivationThreshold [id=26, businessTypeName=parts, roleName=System Admin, thresholdValue=30]
UserDeactivationThreshold [id=27, businessTypeName=parts, roleName=Dealer, thresholdValue=25]
UserDeactivationThreshold [id=40, businessTypeName=BCP Attachments, roleName=System Admin, thresholdValue=20]
```

from this list, am having two different `businessTypeName` (parts and BCP) for the same `roleName` (System Admin). so for i have to select the least `thresholdValue` of two.

Expected output : i have to select `thresholdValue=20` for `System Admin` instead of `thresholdValue=30`

Am using Java 6 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do that by streaming the `ArrayList<UserDeactivationThreshold>` like this:

**Java 8 and higher:**

```
List<UserDeactivationThreshold> thresholds = new ArrayList<>();

// fill the list somehow

// then stream for minimum thresholdValue:
UserDeactivationThreshold minThreshold = thresholds..stream()
                .min(Comparator.comparing(UserDeactivationThreshold::getThresholdValue))
                .get()
```

**Java 7 or lower:**

```
public static UserDeactivationThreshold getMinimumThresholdFor(String roleName, List<UserDeactivationThreshold> thresholds) {
    List<UserDeactivationThreshold> mins = new ArrayList<>();

    // first, fetch all items with the given role name into a list
    for (int i = 0; i < thresholds.size(); i++) {
        UserDeactivationThreshold udt = thresholds.get(i);

        if (udt.getRoleName().equals(roleName)) {
            mins.add(udt);
        }
    }

    // then create an instance to be returned, initialized with null
    UserDeactivationThreshold min = null;

    // now go through the list of items with the given role name
    for (int i = 0; i < mins.size(); i++) {
        // take the current item
        UserDeactivationThreshold current = mins.get(i);
        // check if minimum is still null
        if (min == null) {
            // if yes, set the minimum to the current item
            min = current;
        // if it is not null anymore, compare min's threshold to current's
        } else if (min.getThreshold() > current.getThreshold()) {
            // and set min to current if current has a lower threshold
            min = current;
        }
    }

    return min;
}
```

For **Java 7 or lower** I have provided a method which takes a `roleName` and the list of `UserDeactivationThreshold`s and will return the entry with the lowest `threshold` for the given `roleName`.

If you want every instance of `UserDeactivationThreshold` for all possible `roleName`s, then I think you should use a `Map<String, UserDeactivationThreshold>` with the `roleName` as key.

Comment: Am using Java 6 Version. Also i have to find minimum value only with `roleName` came multiple times. Then i have to choose minimum `thresholdValue`

Comment: Ah, ok... I will update my answer soon… By the way, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Am trying with the normail for loop. forloop within forloop to compare each record.

Comment: @Karthikeyan have a look at the new example I edited into the answer.

Comment: why do we need to pass `roleName` to the method. and how its possible to pass as parameter. Because, have to compare the `roleName` from the `thresholds` objects.

Comment: @Karthikeyan You could create a list of unique role names and execute this method for each role name in that list. Then you will get the minimum `UserDeactivationThreshold` per role name. Note: This method is just an example, you can take view the code, understand how it gets the minimum for a single role name and then use it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Java 6 gives a lot of restrictions here. I even forgot the syntax now (Streams are very cool)

```
List<UserDeactivationThreshold> thresholds = new ArrayList<>();


Map<String, UserDeactivationThreshold> adminUDTMap = new HashMap<String, UserDeactivationThreshold>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < thresholds.size() ; i++){
    UserDeactivationThreshold udt = thresholds.get(i);
    UserDeactivationThreshold udtTemp = adminUDTMap.get(udt.getRoleName());
    if(udt.getThresholdValue() < udtTemp.getThresholdValue()){
        adminUDTMap.put(udt.getRoleName(), udt);
    }
}
```

Rest is I guess easy enough. Java 8 lambda is very powerful for such requirements and can produce required results in single command.

Answer (score 0):

For Java 6 you can use comparator, I just wrote a method you can pass your List to this and it will return you the expected value or you can change it to get the expected object based on your need :

```
public static Integer getMinimumThresholdFor(List<UserDeactivationThreshold> userDeactivationThresholds ) {
        userDeactivationThresholds.sort(new Comparator<UserDeactivationThreshold>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(UserDeactivationThreshold o1, UserDeactivationThreshold o2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return o1.thresholdValue.compareTo(o2.thresholdValue);
            }
        });

        return userDeactivationThresholds.get(0).getThresholdValue();

    }
```

I see you are looking for a solution to select lowest threshold value based on  each roleName in that case you can use the below logic/ function:

```
public static Map<String, UserDeactivationThreshold> getMinimumThresholdForEachRoleName(List<UserDeactivationThreshold> userDeactivationThresholds ) {
            Map<String, UserDeactivationThreshold> thresholdMap = new HashMap<String, UserDeactivationThreshold>();
            for (Iterator iterator = userDeactivationThresholds.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                UserDeactivationThreshold userDeactivationThreshold = (UserDeactivationThreshold) iterator.next();
                if(thresholdMap.get(userDeactivationThreshold.getRoleName())!= null) {
                    if(thresholdMap.get(userDeactivationThreshold.getRoleName()).getThresholdValue().compareTo(userDeactivationThreshold.getThresholdValue())>1){
                        thresholdMap.put(userDeactivationThreshold.getRoleName(), userDeactivationThreshold);
                    }
                } else {
                    thresholdMap.put(userDeactivationThreshold.getRoleName(), userDeactivationThreshold);
                }
            }
            return thresholdMap;

        }
```

Hope that helps.